# How to represent an array of numbers as characters

Tags: matlab

I have a sine wave which is wavelet thresholded (say soft thresholding). How to program so that the signal is transformed using a discrete wavelet transform and then display the coefficients of the signal in this new basis using alphabetical characters rather than using numbers.

For instance: `$a=(\text{coeff}_1,\text{coeff}_2,...,\text{coeff}_9)$, $b=(\text{coeff}_{10},...,\text{coeff}_{19})$`, and so on. Now, the depending on how many numbers are to be represented by a single character, a rule can be formed such that say if the number of alphabets are 8 and the length of the signal is 1000 then how to specify a sliding window for the assignment of characters?It is possible that there can be more than one instance of $a$ coefficients; they are not unique numbers. This is similar to a compression technique. The characters of alphabets can be assigned by Markov Method.

Comment: Always,an upvoted Question...nvr an answer!I should try my hand in quizzing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lets see if I've got your question. You have an array with numbers, and you want matlab to display it as letters with this strange syntax. Try something like:

```
a=[];
for i=1:length(sinewave)
   a=[a sprintf('%c',sinewave(i))]; % dont remember if %c is to char, see sprintf help, but if it doesnt works use %s 
end

a=reshape(a,[length(a) 10]); % just because you wanted to show 10 letters per row
```

Anyway, this is just a clue, trying to help you. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the much anticipated response.You are quite right,but the problem is that the numbers are not always integers and unique. So,the problem is how to club/represent the similar numbers by the same symbol/character.

Comment: What do you mean by similar numbers?

Comment: Well,the wavelet coefficients or the elements of the array a may not be unique,a number can repeat itself i guess.So,there should be a linear search for clubbing those numbers under one character. And in your code,dont we need to mention which characters to use?Or does it take the ASCII by default?How to proceed without converting to ASCII and specifiying from a predefined character set.

Comment: It will use ascii, because sprintf will probably call some standard C function inside it, or something like that. But if you want to map it, it's ok if you know how your array behaves. You could use some samples  to check how the numbers will behave and than think how to map them into letters.

Comment: Thank you,could you kindly append your answer without using ascii how to map into pre defined set of letter?

Comment: Imagine you want number 2333 to be letter 'a', and 2334 to be 'b'. Ascii number for letter 'a' is 97, on decimal. One way would be just do sinewave-(2333-97), than do char(sinewave) and reshape. But if you want to map everything into new chars, you need to change their numbers into the ascii number, it will be kinda boring to do that. If you have double and floats, you can do multiply them by some number so that you have unique integer numbers (or at least to have some sensibility you want to have), and than remap them into ascii chars the way you like.